# Specify properties once, not twice

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

When I have a pipeline in **Jenkins 2 multi-branch** project like :

```
node {
  stage 'Stage Checkout'

  // Checkout code from repository and update any submodules
  //checkout scm
  git credentialsId: 'myId', url: 'https://gitlab.mycompany.com'

  stage 'Stage Build'
  echo "My branch is: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
}
```

I do need to specify the `credentialsId` and `URL` twice:

1. in the Jenkinsfile like above
2. in the Jenkins UI [image]

It seems to be **redundant** to specify these two properties twice. Is there a possibility to **specify them only once**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
checkout scm
```

Instead of `git` command, `checkout scm` will use the data provided in the Jenkins configuration.